# Moving ship back and foward towards ship's direction in C#

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am trying to code two suitable keys to update position in the forward/backward direction of Ship travel at a suitable velocity and what I came up with is : 
In Cmodel :

```
//Update method
        public void Update(Vector3 position, Vector3 orientation)  
        {

            //TO DO - Create an updated version of this.local matrix


            this.local *= Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z);

            this.local *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);
        }
```

Than in Game1:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        //Update the camera
        camera.Update();

       KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        // The time since Update was called last.
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        float RotationAngle = 0;
        RotationAngle += elapsed;
        float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
        RotationAngle = RotationAngle % circle;

        Vector3 orientation = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            orientation.X = RotationAngle;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            orientation.X = -RotationAngle;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            orientation.Y = RotationAngle;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            orientation.Y = -RotationAngle;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
            orientation.Z = RotationAngle;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.X))
            orientation.Z = -RotationAngle;


        //TO DO - Code two suitable keys to update position in the forward/backward direction of Ship travel at a suitable velocity


        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
            position.Z = 1f;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B))
            position.Z = 1f;


        //Update the first model i.e. the Ship
        scene[0].Update(position, orientation);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

The thing is when i rotate the nose of the ship left or right  these buttons still work like back and foward towards me (camera). What do Iadd to make it move back and foward of the ship "nose", ship's direction?

ANSWER!!!!
All I had to do to make it work was to multiply matrixes with diferently: Rotation first than Translate and at the end Local!!! Thank you everyboy for answers. It was really sitting on my head big time!

```
this.local = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position.X, position.Y, position.Z) * this.local;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but do you want to assign new values, rather than modifying the previous values? `position.Z -= 50.0f;` and `position.Z += 50.0f`, respectively.

Comment: I,ve got this ship in the middle of my screen, i can rotate it left, right, up, down and move back and foward. The movement back and foward is only like from the point of view of the camera. I would like it to be moving back and foward toward where it is looking. I am sorry if this is not clear but i am brand new to xna

Comment: I would say get 2 enums, one with RelativeDirection as in, left, right, forward, backward. And one with Absolutedirection (north, east, south, west) then you can say that if the absolutedirect is east, and you turn left, that it should go north. Should be able to accomplish this pretty easily

Answer (score 0):

Remember your math lessons at school! Your "ship" is at one point, and you have the speed/distance and angle where you want to move it. Here is some pseude code to help:

```
float a = math.rad(angle);
float newX = currentX + math.sin(a) * distanceToMove;
float newZ = currentZ - math.cos(a) * distanceToMove;
```

This is a basic vector calculation, how ever I'm not sure about the axis right now, but if you tinker a little bit with X,Y and Z and you should figure it out! Sorry if the above formula is wrong, it is a loooong time ago since I actually did math like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I might not be right since I've done this in AS3.

When you rotate the ship, u need to recalculate it's movement.

To simplify, if there is only `X` and `Y`, and that key press moves you 10 units (whatever your unit is (pixels for example)). When you rotate your ship to some angle, you need to recalculate its movement on both `X` and `Y` axes.

His moving function looks like this:

```
Ship.X += Math.Cos(currentAngle) * Ship.DefaultMoveUnits;
Ship.Y += Math.Sin(currentAngle) * Ship.DefaultMoveUnits;
```

It is same principle for `XYZ`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move forward, you need to get the orientation of the ship. This is not the problem, as you set the orientation already in your code: `Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z);`
Using this RotationMatrix you can extract the values needed for the direction the ships nose is pointing towards:

```
//this method uses 'orientation' as the current orientation of the ship
public Vector3 GetForward()
{
    Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z);
    //i don't know the matrix structure of XNA, but it should be possible
    //to access each field seperately
    //M13 is here: row 1, column 3
    //M23 is here: row 2, column 3 and so on
    return new Vector3(rotation.M13, rotation.M23, rotation.M33);
}

//now that you got the appropriate vector
//you just can move into the direction of this vector like
Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
if(keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
{
    position += ship.GetForward();
}

position *= elapsed;

//update the position of the ship here
```

You can get the right and up vector with the same method, just using the other columns of the rotation matrix:

```
public Vector3 GetRight()
{
    Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z);
    return new Vector3(rotation.M11, rotation.M21, rotation.M31);
}

public Vector3 GetUp()
{
    Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z);
    return new Vector3(rotation.M12, rotation.M22, rotation.M32);
}
```

You can get all other directions (backward, left, down) by negating the corresponding vector. So to get the backward direction you use `-GetForward()`.

Comment: Still cannot do it. I am just too week I think. It should be very easy thing to do. Just to get current y axis of the ship and than go straight this direction.

Comment: @Dave What exactly is your problem? Better to say, which part of my answer do you not understand?

Comment: I have an answer!!! Thank you very much everybody, couple more hours on it and there it is! All I had to do was to multiply matrixes diferently! 30sek of work and 12h to find it!

Answer (score 0):

To make it work all I had to do was to change the matrix multiplying:

this.local = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(orientation.Y, orientation.X, orientation.Z) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position.X, position.Y, position.Z) * this.local;